# Fixed inverted Buffer in QGIS for 100 meters is not working

Tags: qgis, buffer

In QGIS I am trying to run a buffer on a polygon layer for 100 meters, it is based on a tutorial so it is supposed to work but it doesn't work.  Someone in another forum suggested that I merge the polygons first but it actually didn't make a buffer at all after that.

I am using WGS84 UTM Zone 33S, the tutorial link is here http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/answers/answers.html#complete-analysis-2

Comment: What is the projection system of your layer? If you want the buffers in meters then the layer should be in a projection system with meters as units. Also can you share the tutorial or the steps you followed?

Comment: is this question relevant? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228951/qgis-buffer-not-recognizing-all-features-in-layer

Comment: the problem is solved here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230736/fixed-buffers-and-interior-buffers-are-not-working-for-a-polygon-that-contains-a/230895?noredirect=1#comment358557_230895

Comment: Janita, it didn't work on mine.

Comment: I reinstalled QGIS and got it to work after using your example.

Answer (score 1):

I was just having a similar issue. My polygon was in NAD 83 UTM coordinates and I set my buffer distance up in meters and the resulting buffer was always blank. I think my issue was that the nodes on my polygon crossed. Check your nodes that you have clear uniform polygons without any nodes intersecting. Hope this helps.