# Fixed Distance Buffer not Buffering Features with Holes

Tags: qgis, buffer

***QGIS 2.18.5***

I've created a viewshed over a hilly area and I would like to add a fixed distance buffer just to compensate for any underestimations from the viewshed plugin's result.

This is the result with a 100m buffer:

[image]

You can see the buffer does not work if the feature has holes in it. Some of the holes are quite large and if filled, will alter the viewshed drastically.

I've also tried the solution from this thread: [Fixed buffers and interior buffers are not working for a polygon that contains a hole](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230736/fixed-buffers-and-interior-buffers-are-not-working-for-a-polygon-that-contains-a)

However I get this result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps some polygon geometries are not valid. Check the topology first.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have any active selections on the layer you are buffering

Comment: All geometry types are WKB type: "Polygon"

No selections are made prior to buffering

Comment: @JamesB - Try the `Fill holes` algorithm from the _Processing Toolbox_.

Comment: @Joseph I've just updated the question as you posted your comment. How about a means to split the features instead, thus splitting the closed holes.

Comment: @JamesB - Split the features which have holes in them?

Comment: Indeed. I'm updating the question to help elaborate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed buffers and interior buffers are not working for a polygon that contains a hole](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230736/fixed-buffers-and-interior-buffers-are-not-working-for-a-polygon-that-contains-a)

Comment: @ahmadhanb thanks for the link, I've updated my question once again